# Form onsubmit with ajax always submits twice the first time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, forms

I have forms with an `onsubmit` handler that performs a search using AJAX and I cannot get them to not submit twice the first time the page is loaded. The form looks like this, using Razor and DevExtreme controls. When the form submits I call a `search()` function which serializes the form and POSTs the data using Ajax and displays results with the result.

No matter what, if I submit via a button click or by pressing enter in a field, `search()` is called twice the first time I submit the form after loading the page. **Subsequent submits only fire once.**

Form:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="search();">
<div>
    <!-- Fields... -->
</div>
<div>
    @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
        .Type(ButtonType.Default)
        .UseSubmitBehavior(true)
        .Text("Search")
    )
</div>
</form>
```

Handler:

```
function search() {
// Build search params from form fields.
let params = new Object();

$("#searchForm").serializeArray()
    .map(item => params[item.name] = item.value);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Search",
    data: params
}).done(result => {
    // Show results...
});
}
```

I've read several other questions here regarding double form submit, but nothing from there has helped. I tried using `event.preventDefault();` in my handler but it would still submit twice.

```
<form id="searchForm" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="search(event);">
```

.

```
function search(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// .....
}
```

If I return false from the handler, it still fires twice. If I change the button to not submit the form and instead call a Javascript function that submits it via jQuery, it still fires twice.

Comment: You don't need `e.preventDefault()` because you have `action="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @Barmar, obviously not since it didn't change anything. I only mentioned it to point out options I have tried.

Comment: I suggest you set a debugger breakpoint in the function, then check the stack to see where it's being called from.

Comment: What if you get rid of the ASP.NET code in the form? I have a suspicion it's related to that. But I've never used ASP.NET.

Comment: @Barmar, debugging and stepping out was a good idea. It turns out there was some global form submit handler added somewhere else for something unrelated that I wasn't even aware of that processed form data and resubmitted it.